# Why ${\rm Ult}(V,{\cal U})\vDash|[id]_{\cal U}|<j_{\cal U}(\kappa)$, when $\cal U$ is a $\delta$-complete fine ultrafilter on $\cal P_\kappa(\alpha)$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

The following argument appears in the proof of Theorem 4.7. in Bagaria-Magidor's paper *Group radicals and strongly compact cardinals*.

Let $\delta<\kappa$ be uncountable cardinals which may be singular and let $\alpha$ be an ordinal such that $\alpha\geq\kappa$. Suppose there exists a $\delta$-complete fine measure $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(\alpha)$, that is, a $\delta$-complete ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(\alpha)=\{x\subseteq\alpha:|x|<\kappa\}$ such that $\{x\in\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(\alpha):a\in x\}\in\mathcal{U}$ for every $a\in\alpha$. Let $j_{\mathcal{U}}:V\longrightarrow Ult(V,\mathcal{U})$ be the corresponding ultrapower embedding. Since $\mathcal{U}$ is $\delta$-complete, then $Ult(V,\mathcal{U})$ is well-founded. Moreover, also by $\delta$-completeness, the critical point of $j_{\mathcal{U}}$ is greater than or equal to $\delta$. Now my question:

Why $Ult(V,\mathcal{U})\vDash|[id]_{\mathcal{U}}|<j_{\mathcal{U}}(\kappa)$?

Thanks in advance.

(I would have added the tag *ultrapowers* if it existed, but it does not and I have no reputation to create it).

Comment: Are you assuming normality?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't know what you mean by this is false in general in the setting of the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I am not. I actually don't know anything about normality (I'm new into ultrapowers). The reference, just in case you want to check, is Bagaria-Magidor's *Group radicals and strongly compact cardinals*. This argument appears in the proof of Theorem 4.7.

Comment: @frch: This is pertinent information and should be given in the question as part of the context (e.g. "I was reading such and such paper, and in the proof of this and that statement ...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $j_{\mathcal U}(\kappa)$ is (the image under transitive collapse of) the equivalence class in the ultrapower of the constant function $c$ with value $\kappa$.  So, by Los's theorem, what needs to be proved is that $|id_{\mathcal U}(a)|<c(a)$ for $\mathcal U$-almost all $a\in\mathcal P_\kappa(\alpha)$. That is, $|a|<\kappa$ for almost all $a$.  But this inequality is in fact true for all $a\in\mathcal P_\kappa(\alpha)$, by definition of $\mathcal 
P_\kappa(\alpha)$.